# How to connect to a BigQuery instance using my gmail account in DataGrip?

Tags: google-bigquery, datagrip

I am trying to connect to BigQuery using my google user account rather than a service account or service key. Im following the steps [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connect-to-bigquery.html#google-user-account)

I am stuck on step 4. I cannot find the "Authentication List". Can someone point it out?

[image]

Edit: screenshot after upgrading driver

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to switch to the latest version of the driver? You can find in the bottom "Switch to driver...".

Comment: I did do that but still don't see a username password thing or the Authentication List. Do you know if default is the right connection type?

Comment: Please file the support request here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your Data Grip version to the newest.

According to the Data Grip [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2022.2/connect-to-bigquery.html), the possibility to use the **Google User Account** option appeared from version 2021.3.

**[2021.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2021.3/connect-to-bigquery.html)**
[image]

**[2021.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2021.2/connect-to-bigquery.html)**
[image]

Comment: Even though I see this is possible I still don't understand how to connect via this option. I still don't see the "Authentication List" that the document describes..

Comment: What version of Data Grip do you use?

Comment: 2021.2.4, Build #DB-212.5457.41 built on Oct 7, 2021

Comment: Ah, after downloading 2022.2.5 from the website, I see the menu for setting up a bigquery connection has changed. I now see the "Authentication" drop down with an option to use a Google User Account. Thanks!